# GWT Bootstrap TextArea multine not working

Tags: gwtbootstrap3

I am using GWTBootstrap3 ,
I have a textArea , I entered 3 different rows in my text area 
But when i display it somewhere it all comes in 1 single row

I thought GWtbootstrap3 textArea will handle the multiLine itself , am i wrong , do i need to do something for this.

please guide

```
                 <b:Column size="XS_12,SM_6,MD_6,LG_4">
                            <b:FormGroup ui:field="formRemarks">
                                <b:FormLabel for="remarksForm" ui:field="remarksForm" >
                                <ui:msg meaning="remarks">Remarks</ui:msg></b:FormLabel>
                                <b:TextArea name="remarks" debugId="remarks" ui:field="remarks" />
                            </b:FormGroup>
                        </b:Column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace existing TextArea line with below:

```
<b:Column size="XS_12,SM_6,MD_6,LG_4">
   <b:FormGroup ui:field="formRemarks">
     <b:FormLabel for="remarksForm" ui:field="remarksForm" >
     <ui:msg meaning="remarks">Remarks</ui:msg></b:FormLabel>
     <b:TextArea name="remarks" rows="4" debugId="remarks" ui:field="remarks"></b:TextArea>
   </b:FormGroup>
</b:Column>
```

Comment: thanks, but with this i get this error : Class TextArea has no appropriate setRows() method:

Comment: I just tried visibleLine="4" instead of rows, but it still displays in 1 line

Comment: My Issue is , I saved text in text area, textarea itself appears in multiple lines,  But the text which i saved there, If later i display that text somewhere else in my other view inside a div, that text displays in 1 Line.

Comment: So if saved a text in 4 lines in TextArea, So later when i display this text anywhere in a div or wherever, it should comes in 4 lines.